# Перемещение персонажа по тачу (юнити 2d)

Tags: разработка-игр, unity3d

Когда пользователь проводит пальцем по экрану вправо, фиксирует палец, не снимает его, персонаж двигается вправо. То же самое и с движением влево. Как такое можно реализовать? Спасибо заранее

Comment: если начало движения должно быть именно при фиксировании пальца, то тогда определить координаты touchstart, и далее при touchmove записать в переменную факт того, что было произведено движение пальцем и в какую сторону, и если за определенное время после последнего touchmove не произошло touchend, то считать, что движение должно начаться

Comment: Если тачмув больше, чем тачстарт, значит двигаться вправо, верно?

Comment: там две координаты: x и y, по определенной из них и рассчитывать. Но еще нужно учесть, как это поведет себя с разными ориентациями экрана

Comment: Я сделал по deltaPosition. Если отрицательное значение  - двигаться влево . Тока не очень нравится результат

Answer (score 1):

Это зависит от того, что именно вы хотите.
На сколько я понял, я так думаю, что данное решение можно реализовать при помощи `Raycast`.
Пример:

```
public Vector3 PointFromTouch()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Ray _ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.touches[0].position);
        RaycastHit _hit = new RaycastHit();
        float distance = 100f;
        Physics.Raycast(_ray, out _hit, distance);
        return _hit.point;
    }
    else
    {
        return new Vector3();
    }
}
```